# Xcode warning: "NSArray may not respond to -addObject"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsarray

In my header file, I have this code:

```
@interface TableViewController : UIViewController 
{
    IBOutlet UITableView *tblListData;
    NSArray *arryData;
}
```

In my class declaration file, I have this implementation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    arryData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"iPhone",@"iPod",@"MacBook",nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Now I get this Xcode warning: `NSArray may not respond to -addObject` for the following code:

```
- (IBAction)AddButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    [arryData addObject:@"Mac Mini"];
    [tblListData reloadData];
}
```

And, sure enough, my `NSArray` is not responding to `addObject`! :(

What should I do?

Answer (score 37):

If you look up the docs, you'll see that [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/) is actually an immutable array (i.e. it can not be modified). That's why the `-addObject:` message is not implemented. Instead, you will need to use [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/).